# How to create a simple crosstab query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, crosstab

I have two tables containing fields as below.

Table 1

```
    | SetID | InQty | Day |
    |  1    |   10  |  1  |
    |  2    |   10  |  2  |
    |  3    |   10  |  3  |
```

Table 2

```
    | SetID | OtQty | Day |
    |  1    |   1   |  5  |
    |  1    |   2   |  6  |
    |  1    |   3   |  7  |
```

SetID in table 2 is linked with SetId in table 1. Day is placed in place of date, just for convenience  only. Expected Output,

```
    | Day  | InQty | OtQty |
    |  1   |   10  |       |
    |  5   |       |   1   |
    |  6   |       |   2   |
    |  7   |       |   3   |
```

Blank Space can be filled with NULL or Zero.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are querying ONLY for set ID = 1 otherwise, I would expect to see in/out values for Set 2 and 3.  You should be able to get with a simple UNION

```
select t1.Day, t1.InQty, 0 OutQty
   from Table1 t1
   where SetID = 1
   order by t1.Day
union select t2.Day, 0, t2.OtQty
   from Table2 t2
   where SetID = 1
```

Now, if you want totals spanning different "setID"s and keeping them differentiated from each other, just add the setID as a column and also add to the group by clause as well.